# Return file in JsonResult or return Json data in ActionResult?

Tags: c#, .net, json, http-post, jsonresult

Using an MVC3 .net controller on the back-end, I am performing an HttpPost to submit a file via the HttpContext.

When the server reads the file, a list of strings is returned with the upload results.

So far, I have been able to get two scenarios working:

1) Return the list of strings as a single, tab-delimited string as a JsonResult

```
string tabSeparatedMessages = "";

foreach (string message in messageLog)
{
    tabSeparatedMessages = tabSeparatedMessages + message;

    if (message != messageLog[messageLog.Count - 1])
    {
        tabSeparatedMessages = tabSeparatedMessages + '\n';
    }
}
return this.Json(new
{
    success = true,
    total = messageLog.Count,
    data = tabSeparatedMessages
}, "text/html", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

2) Return the list of strings in a text file as an ActionResult

```
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    foreach (string message in messageLog)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

return File(fileName, "text/plain", "UPLOAD_RESULTS.txt");
```

My problem is that I want elements from each of these methods but am having difficulty combining the two.  I want the JsonResult so that I can return a boolean 'success' value to release a modal, waiting message on the client.  I want the ActionResult so that the client can simply download a file instead of parsing the list of strings into the GUI components.

Is there a way to return a text file to be downloaded as part of the JsonResult or return Json data with the ActionResult?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only return one result type at a time. If I were you and I really needed that upload_results.txt to be downloaded to the client I would have a parameter in my json result that is a reference to the file on the server.

So the client first get the response that the upload was successful and you hide the modal dialog, then with javascript you make another request for the upload_results.txt file.

Comment: It is my understanding that MVC3 controllers are deconstructed after each request.  Do you or anyone else have any recommendations on how to persist the user-to-file relationship between the file-generating request and the downloading request?  I'm thinking about storing the temporary file path in the database along with the user who generated it, but a single user could still have multiple files associated with him or her, and I am not sure how to ensure that the file being downloaded is from the correct request.

Comment: Store the file in the cache in the webserver using a GUID key that is sent to the client and used to call for the file. That solves the problem if residual files on the server as the cache entry can be set to perish in 5 minutes or what you find suitable.

Comment: As David describes it is how I would have done it. The GUID key is the one you want to send in your json-response, and then make a request for the file tagged with that GUID in the cache or if you prefer database.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above, send down the JSON and store the file temporarily on the webserver. Have the path to this file in the JSON and then just do a GET